# PostgreSQL JDBC Driver rounds crops double value

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm  using PostgreSql 9.3 together with the postgresql-9.3-1101 JDBC Driver. 
And there is a really strange behavior with the `PreparedStatements`.

Here is the example:
First I create a test table:

```
CREATE TABLE double_test
(
   id          numeric(18)     NOT NULL
);
```

After that that i run following code:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0");
try {
    conn = BeanUtils.getBean("dataSource", DataSource.class).getConnection();
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    conn.createStatement().execute("DELETE from double_test ");
    conn.commit();
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO double_test (id )VALUES (?)");
    double input = 1234567890123456d;
    System.out.println("Input:" + df.format(input));
    stmt.setDouble(1, input);
    stmt.execute();
    conn.commit();

    ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT id FROM double_test ");
    rs.next();
    System.out.println("Output:" + df.format(rs.getDouble(1)));
    rs.close();
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e1);
} finally {
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

The output of the code will be:

```
Input: 1234567890123456
Output:1234567890123460
```

Which gets me very confused, after the 15. digit the Postgres JDBC Driver starts to round. The inserted data gets corrupted, without any further notice!

Did I miss anything here? Has my code any errors?

Or is this a bug in the Driver? If so, I really wonder that no one noticed this yet.

Maybe working with `BigDecimal` will prevent the data from corrupting, but this is just a workaround.

Comment: Using `BigDecimal` is **not** a "workaround" it is the correct way to deal with `numeric` columns. `double` is an *approximate* data type:  http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but he/she is putting one `double` in, and getting a different one out.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sure are all floating values approximate, but we are talking not about a rounding of decimal points. It just cuts the value after the 15. digit and fill it with zeros zeros. Just add digits to the example and you will see.

Comment: @Orism Floating point errors don't just happen after the decimal point.  They can happen with numbers like these ones too.  However, that's not what's happening here.

Comment: @Orism `1234567890123456` is just a shorthand for `0.1234567890123456E16`, floating point numbers will be rounded at their significand parts while PostgreSQL's `numeric` does not round its value. This is why you should choose a representation at client's side, which doesn't apply rounding.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on floating point approximation. I tried the same code with three other Databases / JDBC Drivers, these are all working as I would expect it. Input == Output.

Comment: The fact is that if you want it to perform correctly in a consistent fashion, you must use `BigDecimal`, as @a_horse_with_no_name has already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

There is a two problem.

First from `Double` class:

```
System.out.println(0.1 + 0.2); //output 0.30000000000000004
```

So usually don't use `Double` (also `Float`).

Second from jdbc driver , it is triying to save database with toString method which class related with `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement`.

Check this:

```
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.00000072")); // print 7.2E-7
```

It is equal but when Jdbc driver  save with this, some precisions corrupt, so I replace

```
    public void setBigDecimal(@Positive int parameterIndex, @Nullable BigDecimal x)
            throws SQLException {
        setNumber(parameterIndex, x); // It is using toString method
    }
```

with this:

```
public void setBigDecimal(@Positive int parameterIndex, @Nullable BigDecimal x)
        throws SQLException {
    checkClosed();
    if (x == null) {
        setNull(parameterIndex, Types.DECIMAL);
    } else {
        bindLiteral(parameterIndex, x.toPlainString(), Oid.NUMERIC); //now using toPlainString
    }

}
```

If you really want to use `Double` or `Float` you can fix like this changes.