# MyBatis | Losing Double Precision on Insertion

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis

My SQL query in MyBatis mapper

```
<foreach collection="ps" item="p" separator=";" open="" close="">
    INSERT INTO ${stageTableName} VALUES(
        #{p.v1},
        #{p.v2},
        #{p.v3},
        #{p.v4},
        #{p.v5},
        #{vx},
        #{p.quantity}
    )
    ON CONFLICT ("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5")
    DO UPDATE SET quantity = ${stageTableName}.quantity + EXCLUDED.quantity
</foreach>
```

`ps` is a List of objects in java.
Everything was working well until today we hit a case where

When p.quantity = `1222371636058.8174`
Then in database what I see quantity is = `1222371636058.82`

- I ran code in debug mode, and I see this is where the round off is being done.
- I ran SQL query with hard coded values, and in that case DB value is store correctly, i.e. `1222371636058.8174`
- But above code rounds it off. And it does only for this number. For example, a smaller number, say `123.8124872` 's precision is stored correctly.

---

- Type of p.quantity in Java - `Double`
- Type of 'quantity' in the table - `NUMERIC(38,7)`
- DB - `Postgres`

Please let me know if anyone knows whats happening here.

Comment: It's most probably happening in Java. Might be related to Java's `Double`. https://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @Wira There are similar reports [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27856598) [2](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1942). The driver (pgjdbc) seems to send the right value, so there might be some issue with the protocol handling in the server side. In any case, you should use `BigDecimal` if precision matters.